# How can I detect inside a Git hook script whether a commit is being initiated by a GUI app?

Tags: git, zsh

### Background which can be skipped

#### (as long as you don't then ask "why do you want to do that?")

I have in the past primarily used the command line for Git, however Fork has some tools that I haven't seen in other GUI Git clients<sup>1</sup>, so I've begun using it to complement Git in the shell.  This creates a problem, however, for my `prepare-commit-msg` hook script, which presents an `fzf`-based UI in the terminal<sup>2</sup>, which breaks Fork.

### TLDR:

I want my `prepare-commit-msg` hook script to be able to detect when it is being triggered by a GUI app, so I can avoid presenting the selection UI in the script, since that prevents Fork from working.

Is there any way of detecting that?

I'm using Zsh but any solution that works in Bash can probably be adapted, if it doesn't already work as-is.

---

<sup>1</sup> by providing a really nice interactive rebase editor (which allows you to *see the code in the commits* **while you're marking them** for fixup, editing, squashing, dropping, or whatever), and by providing a really nice history browser.

<sup>2</sup> for selecting emojis from a thematically organized list, to give commit messages a quick & meaningful visual cue to make scanning them easier.  (I didn't like any of the existing emoji managers like gitmoji, so I basically rolled my own to work the way I wanted it to work.)

Comment: can you check if `tty` returns a value which can be discriminated ? e.g : add `tty >> /tmp/tty.list` in your `prepare-commit-msg` hook, and check `/tmp/tty.list`

Comment: another way could be to use a wrapper when you start Fork, which sets an env variable (e.g: `GIT_GUI_FORK=1`), and check that env variable in your script.

Comment: This needs more focus; questions in *I need this in either language A or language B* fashion are too broad for SO.

Comment: @oguzismail: if you're referring to the shell as a "language", Zsh and Bash have a HUGE overlap.  If I said "I'm working in Ruby 2.7, but I'm just as happy with a solution in Ruby 2.6.6" would you have a problem with that? And nonetheless, I didn't say what you're describing me as saying.

Comment: If Ruby 2.7 and and 2.6.6 had a huge difference in syntax and semantics, I would have. Zsh deviated from traditional UNIX shells long ago, now it's barely compatible with Bash even while emulating Sh. So, if you're looking for a solution portable to both, use the [tag:sh] tag, otherwise choose one of them.

Comment: Please reread my question.  Never did I ask for anything portable to both.  I clearly said that I'm using zsh (and therefore obviously would prefer that), but since there are so many more bash users I'm happy to settle for a bash solution that I can then figure out how to adapt to zsh.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're less interested in whether the commit is being initiated by a GUI app and more in whether a terminal is available when you're committing so you can display contents to the user.  If that's the case, then the program you want to use is `tty`, which will determine whether the standard input is a terminal.

You would use it something like this (portable POSIX sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

# No terminal? No problem.
tty >/dev/null 2>&1 || exit 0

# Interact with the user here.
```